# Pointer memory address to binary conversion in C?

Tags: c, embedded, fft

I'm trying to implement the fast fourier transform from first principles. One of the first steps in doing so is to reorder the input data to a specific sequence from which a radix-2 butterfly algorithm can be applied. This specific sequence is achieved through bit reversal of the positions of the array as illustrated below:

[image: bit reversal]

The way I thought to do this was, given an array of real sampled data, to create a pointer which references the first position of the array. Then to use that pointer to convert the memory address of the first position of the data array to a binary number, perform bit reversal on it, convert back to hexadecimal and to set the first position of a new array equal to the dereferenced value of that 'bit reversed' memory address. Doing this in a loop I would be able to increase the original pointer each time, work out the 'reversed' address and populate the new array with the values in the correct order.

I have two questions:

1. Is this even good programming practice? I know that setting pointers to specific addresses is frowned upon but I figure that the arrays are allocated in memory on startup so it should be okay.
2. How would I convert a pointer value to a binary value using C language? I thought of something like this:

   int sampledData [8];
   int * pointer = samples;
   int hex_address = (int)pointer;

Comment: Computing an address on an array is not unprecedented in C; in fact, the usual array addressing actually does that.  I'm not sure why you want to work with the address as an actual value, however.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the only reason is to be able to convert that actual address to a binary value so that I can bit reverse it to get the required order.

Comment: You must be thinking of the index of the array, not the memory address of one of its elements.  The index of the array starts at zero; the memory addresses of the array elements do not.

Comment: Recall that a **pointer** in C is not an index to an array element; it is a pointer to an arbitrary memory address.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so the pointer itself is not pointing to the specific memory address at which an array element is stored?

Comment: As Robert Harvey said, bit reverse must be done on the index. so `int sampledData [8]; int * pointer = samples; int hex_address = (int)pointer;` is not the good way. You do `not` need to manipulate pointers. There are many tricky algorithms to compute bit_reverse, but as a start, the simpler is to define a table and to use it to do bit reverse. `int rev={0,4,2,6,1,5,3,7};` Then you extract the 3 LSB of array index, compute `rev[i]` and write it back in the LSB position and you can adress your array with this index.

Comment: I think the confusion here arises from the book using the term "address" to mean "array index."  Those two things are not the same in C, though they are very closely related.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you. I misunderstood what the book was saying. The problem is much simpler when reversing array indexes.

Comment: There is no conversion necessary - it is a digital computer, it already is a binary value.  decimal, hexadecimal and probably what you mean by "binary value", are simply human readable representations using characters to represent digits, no integer or pointer value is _stored_ in hex or decimal they are simply representations of binary values for presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an FFT, you don't want to bit-reverse an address pointer (which might not be aligned to a suitable boundary for the FFT length), you want to bit-reverse a zero-based array index (sometimes implemented in C as a pointer offset to access an array).

Very commonly, the permutation is done "in place" where the elements of the array are swapped (using a temporary variable) using both the original and the bit-revered index, rather than copied to a new array, which requires more memory (larger data cache footprint, etc.).